# WiFi packet loss on 5Ghz when uploading

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop, wifi-configuration

The ping to my router (Netgear D6400) from my laptop (Intel AC-9260 160MHz) over 5Ghz usually sits at around 2ms-10ms with < 1% packet loss with a -80db connection (ac). When I start a download bandwidth test via https://fast.com/, I get around 60ms-80ms latency to my router. Then when I run the upload test, I get really high packet loss (i.e. around 80-90%)

This doesn't really affect me when I'm browsing the web or doing other such activities, but when I play some games (e.g. Overwatch), the amount of packet loss reaches around 50-60%. This makes the games practically unplayable.

I have considered switching to a wired connection, but that's not really an option because my house isn't wired for it.

The WiFi settings on the AP for 5ghz are:

- Fragmentation length: 2346
- CTS/RTS threshold: 2347
- Preamble mode: Short preamble
- a/n/ac
- Implicit beamforming: enabled

I have tried disabling the Windows connection limit, but to no avail.

Laptop settings (related to wifi):

- 802.11a/b/g Wireless Mode: 6. Dual Band 802.11a/b/g
- 802.11n/ac Wireless Mode: 802.11ac
- ARP offload for WoWLAN: Enabled
- Channel Width for 5GHz: Auto
- Fat Channel Intolerant: Disabled
- Global BG Scan blocking: Never
- GTK rekeying for WoWLAN: Enabled
- MIMO Power Save Mode: Auto SMPS
- Mixed Mode Protection: RTS/CTS Enabled
- NS offload for WoWLAN: Enabled
- Packet Coalescing: Enabled
- Preferred Band: 1. No Preference
- Roaming Aggressiveness: 1. Lowest
- Sleep on WoWLAN Disconnect: Disabled
- Throughput Booster: Enabled
- Transmit Power: 5. Highest
- U-APSD support: Disabled

There are no other networks on the same channel as the 5Ghz wifi
[image: Channel of wifi]

Comment: Have you tried 2.4GHz for comparison? How far away from the WiFi are you? 10ms to the wifi is already poor, bufferbloat could account for the rest. Try the speed tests at http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest which can advise on such issues.

Comment: I've tried using 2.4GHz, but that doesn't seem to fix anything. I still have around 10ms ping I'm testing this sitting around 2.5m from the WiFi AP. The DSLreport says that I have really bad bufferbloat.

Comment: I have narrowed the latency to the AP down to a problem with my laptop. Another laptop right next to me has around 1-2ms ping to 192.168.0.1, while this one has 7-15ms now.

Comment: Try googling "reduce bufferbloat" + your router or laptop name or start from https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/bloat/wiki/What_can_I_do_about_Bufferbloat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there were many different issues.

1. Intel's AC-9260 apparently doesn't have good 802.11ac support, so I disabled that (now using 802.11n).
2. The 2.4GHz network was set to 20MHz/40MHz coexistence. When I turned that off, the packet loss decreased dramatically although I am still using the 5GHz band (????).
3. Installing WLAN optimizer and disabling background scan + enabling streaming mode.
4. Disabling windows' option to download updates from PCs on this network.

These lowered the median ping to around 2ms - much better than before. There are still occasional ping spikes. I will edit this answer to include my fix for that if I ever find one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few things to improve your situation:

- shorten the wireless range (be closer to the emitter)
- use 2.4GHz instead (it has higher range than 5GHz)
- limit the number of simultaneous open connections from your router to something decent (like 100, depends on model/specs)
- pick a wireless channel that is not near others (of neighbors - if you detect a network on channel 3 don't use channel 2, use 7 or 8)
- get a better router (with greater throughput, greater range and greater number of simultaneous connections supported)
- use traffic shaping if supported (many router do support it) and prioritize the type of traffic you need not to be interrupted